# How to send this D3.js element to another element's on-click function in this recursive Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, d3.js

I'm experimenting with and modifying [**this**](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) example of d3.js to draw a tree based on a JSON tree structure. This is what part of the tree looks like to start out with:

[image]

I'm trying to modify it such that clicking on the text changes the color of the associated circle to red.

But this turns out to be quite difficult because it is a recursive function. In the snippet below I added a function `myFunction` that changes the color of the circle and I call it from the text's `on-click` function. I'm passing in the circle I just created.

```
function myFunction(d, myCircle) {
  myCircle.style("fill", "red");
}



var myCircle = nodeEnter.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 1e-6)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

nodeEnter.append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
  .on("click", myFunction(d, myCircle));
```

When I make this change and click on the text "graph", look what happens. All the siblings of that node turn red:

[image]

Here is the [**plunker of this broken code**](https://plnkr.co/edit/3aQX7Arm8JbgAxMb7vSe?p=preview). You can try it yourself.

This is because of the recursion. The object for ALL the siblings' circles are being sent to `myFunction()`. That's not what I need. But I don't know how to make this work correctly. Please help me by explaining how I can implement this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its not recursion.
When you do this:

```
function myFunction(d, myCircle) {
  myCircle.style("fill", "red");
}
```

Here myCircle is all the circle selection so when you click all the opened nodes become red.

You should approach this problem like:

```
function myFunction(d) {
  //get all the circles
  d3.selectAll("circle")[0].forEach(function(e){
    //get the data associated with the circle
    var d1 = d3.select(e).data()[0];
    if (d1.name == d.name){//check if the data's name and one passed is same
      d3.select(e).style("fill", "red");//change color fr only that node.    
    }
  })

}
```

working code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/beUL2Rjs6BwaTbaphr6O?p=preview)

**Another Way**

No need of the `myFunction` you have made, just do the following in click function.

```
  .on("click", function(d) {
          d3.select(this.parentNode).select("circle").style("fill", "red")
        });
```

working code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/iVK7c8a0qF0gk6lOMpBH?p=preview)

Comment: Second way is a lot cleaner :)